# Why it is giving me 'Cannot read property 'deleteProduct' of undefined' error react Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am getting an error when deleting one row in react js. error is 'Cannot read property 'deleteProduct' of undefined'. also is there any simple way to delete data from the database using custom api. below is my complete code for deleting data from the database.

Here is my code for deleting row-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
export default class FetchedData extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      UserData:[],
      response: {}
      };
    this.headers=[
      {key:1,label:'Name'},
      {key:2,label:'Department'},
      {key:3,label:'Marks'},
    ];
    this.deleteProduct=this.deleteProduct.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
  this.lookupInterval = setInterval(() => {
    fetch("https://www.veomit.com/test/zend/api/fetch.php")
    .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
    .then(result => {
                this.setState({
                    UserData:result
                })
        .catch(error => {
        console.log(
          "An error occurred while trying to fetch data from Foursquare: " +error
        );
      });
    });
  }, 500)
  }

  deleteProduct(userId) {
    const { UserData } = this.state;

    const apiUrl = 'https://www.veomit.com/test/zend/api/delete.php';
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('userId', userId);

    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    }

    fetch(apiUrl, options)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result,
            UserData: UserData.filter(item => item.id !== userId)
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      )
  } 
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              {
                        this.headers.map(function(h) {
                            return (
                                <th key = {h.key}>{h.label}</th>
                            )
                        })
                        }
            </tr>
          </thead> 
          <tbody>
              {
                        this.state.UserData.map(function(item, key) {             
                        return (
                                <tr key = {key}>
                                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                                  <td>{item.department}</td>
                                  <td>{item.marks}</td>
                  <td><span onClick={() => this.deleteProduct(item.id)}>Delete</span></td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
          </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me remove this error.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Any particular reason why you use arrow functions in your fetch but not in your map? Cause in your fetch, you don't really need them until you come to `this.setState`. So you seem to know the principle (you also use them in your element onClick functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping function is creating a new scope:

```
this.state.UserData.map(function(item, key) {             
                    return (
                            <tr key = {key}>
                              <td>{item.name}</td>
                              <td>{item.department}</td>
                              <td>{item.marks}</td>
              <td><span onClick={() => this.deleteProduct(item.id)}>Delete</span></td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })
```

Making it an arrow function should solve the issue:

```
this.state.UserData.map((item, key) => {             
                    return (
                            <tr key = {key}>
                              <td>{item.name}</td>
                              <td>{item.department}</td>
                              <td>{item.marks}</td>
              <td><span onClick={() => this.deleteProduct(item.id)}>Delete</span></td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to losing context here:

```
{
                        this.state.UserData.map(function(item, key) {             
                        return (
                                <tr key = {key}>
                                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                                  <td>{item.department}</td>
                                  <td>{item.marks}</td>
                  <td><span onClick={() => this.deleteProduct(item.id)}>Delete</span></td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
```

Change the function to an arrow function to autobind the callback:

```
{
                        this.state.UserData.map((item, key) => {             
                        return (
                                <tr key = {key}>
                                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                                  <td>{item.department}</td>
                                  <td>{item.marks}</td>
                  <td><span onClick={() => this.deleteProduct(item.id)}>Delete</span></td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
```